# Is there any faster way to match records with values present in a column in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fetch values that are not present in a column in another table. Currently what i am using is

```
and [tPlayerTag].TagId NOT IN (select RequiredTagId from dbo.tPrize(NOLOCK) 
where RequiredTagId is not null)
```

This is present inside my where clause .
It's working completely fine but i think it may slow down my query when dealing with a bigger table(tPrize). Is there any faster way to rewrite this logic ?

Comment: See this - useful post for your query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists

Answer (score 1):

you can use `not exists`

Choosing one over another, of course, depends on a situation: on volume of data that driven and driving queries return. In the case of `[NOT] IN operator` inner query (..where id in (select id from table )) is a driving query whereas in the case of `[NOT] EXISTS` outer query is a driving query. So if the sub-query (inner query) returns small amount of data because of either a table in the sub-query contains small number of rows or there is intensive filtering applied to the sub-query [NOT] IN operator may give better performance. If the sub-query returns large volume of data or the major filtering is happening in outer-query `[NOT] EXISTS operator` is preferable.

```
and [tPlayerTag].TagId NOT exists (select RequiredTagId from dbo.tPrize(NOLOCK) 
where RequiredTagId is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inplace of `in` you can use `exists` and also inplace of `not in` you can `not exists` 
and try like this it will work.

Performance wise you have to use `not exists`

```
[tPlayerTag].TagId NOT exists (select RequiredTagId from dbo.tPrize(NOLOCK) 
where RequiredTagId is not null)
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to use `not exists` rather than `not in`, because `NULL` values do not affect the result.  You seem to know this is a problem because of your `where` clause.

The expression is:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.tPrize p
            WHERE p.RequiredTagId = tPlayerTag.TagId
           )
```

For performance, you want an index on `tPrize(RequiredTagId)`.  This is the index that will make the performance more scalable.